# How to convert a matrix to a raster file and how to calculate means across different regions in R

Tags: r

I have a datset, which is

```
dat<-matrix(seq(1:5290),c(115,46))
```

1. How can I convert `dat` to a raster file with GIS - related metadata such as map projection?
2. and then how to map the data to a us map with

   ```
   lon <- seq(-124.25,length=115,by=0.5)    
   lat <- seq(26.25,length=46,by=0.5)
   ```
3. what should I do if I want to calculate the mean of each state? or specific region?

thanks very much for your feedback.

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
library(raster)
library(maps)

dat<-matrix(seq(1:5290),c(115,46))
```

Create a raster with your desired extent

```
r <- raster(dat)
e <- extent(c(-124.5, -67.25, 26.25, 48.75))
extent(r) <- e
```

and plot it

```
plot(r)
map("usa", add=T)
```

take the mean over the whole raster

```
mean(getValues(r))
```

mean over a region

```
r.sub <- crop(r, c(-100, -54, 40, 45))
mean(getValues(r.sub))
```

---

### Extract from polygons

You need a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame. Here I am creating a dummy one with `readWKT()` but you could also read a shapefile with `readShapePoly()` from the `maptools` package.

```
library(rgeos)
poly <- readWKT("POLYGON((-100 30, -100 31, -70 30, -88 29, -100 30))")
plot(r)
plot(poly, add=T)
```

And extract the mean:

```
dat <- extract(r, poly)
sapply(dat, mean)
```

Comment: This works great. Is there a way that we can add polygons on the map representing different ecoregions and calculate the means of different ecoregions and then map the ecoregions with the mean value.

Comment: This looks exactly what I want. I will use the shapefile from http://www.fs.fed.us/rm/ecoregions/products/map-ecoregions-united-states/     I will test if I can get it done. thanks.

Comment: ecoregions.shp <- readShapePoly("eco-us-shp/eco-us.sh",proj4string=CRS("+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs")) # <--- read in a LL WGS84 shapefile  then the extract(r,ecoregions.shp) gave me all the null values.

Comment: your proj4string suggests different projections. Where you able to plot them? did the plots match?

Comment: I want to plot them on the top of plot(r). They do not match with each other. This is where the shape file come from http://www.fs.fed.us/rm/ecoregions/products/map-ecoregions-united-states/  How can I plot them on the same plot?

Comment: thanks very much for the answers. please ignore the last question I asked.